# Convert integer to byte

Tags: c#, .net, hex

I have program in C#.
I want to convert an int to HEX and after that convert it to a byte.
But there is a problem in the 3rd line:

```
int i = 10;
string str = i.ToString("X");
byte b = Convert.ToByte(str);
```

Please help me.

Comment: I assume you realize you can convert the int to a byte directly, and have a complex scenario where this makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

```
byte b = byte.Parse(str, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte b = Convert.ToByte(str, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    uint ui = 0;
    ui = checked((uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32("10"));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:x2}", ui));
```